# Bigcommerce API start

Tags: bigcommerce

first of all, sorry for this silly question 
    but I am new to use big commerce API and I searched and found many threads but not works for me . 
    the composer created a directory vendor
    then its root I have to create a file index.php and put this code but it's showing me the blank page

```
    <?php 
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

    Bigcommerce::configure(array(

    'store_url' => 'https://store-xxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/',
    'username' => 'xxxx',
    'api_key' => 'xxxx'
    ));
    Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);

    $ping = Bigcommerce::getTime();

    if ($ping) echo $ping->format('H:i:s');


    $filter = array("page" => 3, "limit" => 30);

    $products = Bigcommerce::getProducts($filter); 

    ?>

Please, someone, explain all steps with the easy understandable process ?
Sometimes it's giving 
Fatal error: Class 'Bigcommerce_Api' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\bigcommerceapi\index.php on line 30

I followed this community
https://c9.io/oschino/bigcommerce-api-php-oauth
 when I clicking the single file link it's showing 404 not found where from I can download big commerce.php file

Also, I want to know if composer created a whole PHP API then is it it is necessary to download big commerce PHP API from Github ? 
I have checked the folder structure and files are same in vendor folder and big commerce git hub files.
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I got solution the bigcoomerce store URL call process is now changed

I changed
Bigcommerce::configure(array(

```
'store_url' => 'https://store-xxxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/',
'username' => 'xxxx',
'api_key' => 'xxxx'
));
```

to like this

Bigcommerce::configure(array(

```
'store_url' => 'https://store-xxxx.mybigcommerce.com',
'username' => 'xxxx',
'api_key' => 'xxxx'
));
```